# Generating random numbers and add to new line

Tags: python

I just started learning python and trying to make this simple program to generate random phone numbers.

"leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers" I get this error when running this code.
I also want to add a code to append all numbers into a new line.

```
Country_Code = "+1"
Country_Code= "646"
Generated_Num = random.randrange(900000, 999999)

print(Country_Code + Country_Code + Generated_Num)
```

Comment: The first line of your code is redundant... The value of the variable `Country_Code` is replaced by `"646"` on line 2. Perhaps you meant another variable name?

Comment: That was a mistake the second var was supposed to be Area_Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use f-strings, which automatically format a data type into a string. With a bit of rearrangement, you can store `country_code` and `area_code` as integers as well.

```py
country_code = 1
area_code = 646
generated_num = random.randrange(900000, 999999)

print(f"+{country_code}{area_code}{generated_num}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment it's very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add (`+` operator) a string, like `Country_Code` and an integer, like `Generated_Num`.

1. You can use commas (',') in the print command:
   `print(Country_Code , Country_Code , Generated_Num)`
2. You can print everything as a string, which is more easily formatted:

```py
phone_str = "%s-%s-%d" % (Country_Code , Country_Code , Generated_Num)
print(phone_str)
```

**NOTE:** You are overwritting `Country_Code` and I do not think  you intended to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment it's very helpful, what are these used for "%s-%s-%d" % ?

Comment: @ImaneAniss: they are c-style string formatting arguments. There are [various ways to format strings in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). I believe that using the format flag, as did JacobLee, is the current *preferred* way. I am just used to doing it that way.
Essentially: ``%s`` ~ string; ``%d`` - decimal (integer). The rest is taken literally

Answer (score 0):

convert `Generated_Num` to a string while using `+` with other strings
`print(Country_Code + Country_Code + str(Generated_Num))`

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np

Country_Code = "+1"
Country_Code= "646"
Generated_Num = np.random.randint(900000, 999999)

print(Country_Code +Country_Code + str(Generated_Num))
```

Comment: Why use numpy for generating random numbers,  especially for someone who says they’re just learning?